# Three.js DeviceOrientationControl makes scene disappear

Tags: three.js, controls, device-orientation

I have a glb model which loads successfully and reacts to mouse movements. However when I add DeviceOrientationControl.js which is intended for mobile devices, the scene disappears. No errors visible in the console. Funny enough, when I change

```
controls = new DeviceOrientationControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

to

```
controls = new DeviceOrientationControls( group, renderer.domElement );
```

it works, but has strangely displaces the model around the axis, which I am not able to readjust manually. Can someone help me find a solution? Why doesn't it work with camera but with group (model directly)?

Also when I add

```
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
```

and disable DeviceOrientationControls, the model works however the desired controls are not, which is my main issue.

Here is my code:

```
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {DeviceOrientationControls} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { DRACOLoader } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
import Stats from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';


var camera, scene, renderer, group, stats, controls, windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,
        mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0;


  
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; 

  var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

window.onload = function () {
    init();
    animate();
      
      $(".loadmain").fadeOut(500);
      }

var startButton = document.getElementById( 'startButton' );
startButton.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

            $("#overlay").fadeOut(700, function(){ 
    $(this).remove();
});
      document.body.className += "loaded";
      document.querySelector("canvas").className += " load";

}, false );



const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/');
dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

    function init() {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 10000);
           controls = new DeviceOrientationControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

            camera.position.set(0, 0, 7);

            camera.zoom = 1;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
           
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.updateMatrixWorld();

        



var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3);
directionalLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1);
directionalLight.position.multiplyScalar(10);
scene.add(directionalLight);
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

            var spotLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xff4000 );
    spotLight1.position.set( -15, 3, -4 );
    spotLight1.target.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    spotLight1.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight1 );

            var spotLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xff0aea );
    spotLight2.position.set( 15, 3, -4 );
    spotLight2.target.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
    spotLight2.intensity = 1.2;
    spotLight2.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight2 );


  group = new THREE.Group();
  group.position.x = 0;

  scene.add( group );
  scene.add( camera );


    gltfLoader.load('../public/res/3D/model.glb', (gltf) => {
      const root = gltf.scene;
      
      root.rotateY(-89.55);

      root.position.x = 0;
      root.position.y = -0.7;
      
      root.castShadow = true; 

      group.add(root);
    });


        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: document.querySelector('canvas'), alpha: true, });

        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

}


function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
      mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouseY = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    
    }

    function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    if (group) {
    group.rotation.y = mouseX * .5;
    group.rotation.x = mouseY * -.5;
  }

        controls.update();
        render();
    }

function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}


    function render() {
       
        //camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

Comment: I found that using DeviceOrientationControls does work with camera, however the camera moves only in x and y position. Is there any way to make DeviceOrientationControls rotate around the object as well instead of only moving in x and y axis?

Comment: Or different approach: is there any way to limit the alpha, beta, gamma values of DeviceOrientationControls as in OrbitControls? I hope someone can help me with this.